# how to increase heap size in intellij idea 2017.1.3?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3. I need to increase the heap size of my Java Application. I have searched on the Internet. And the solutions didn't work.
Method 1: run-edit configuration, I altered the option to 10240M,but got error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeaBn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1bTL.png)

Method 2: I have edited the VM options,but failed again.
I also searched on stackoverflow, but the answers were 4 years age, and didn't apply to my situation.
How can I increase the heap size?

Comment: have you tried: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties ?

Comment: I have tried, it didn't work.

Comment: I think you want to go to 1024M not 10240M... or?

Comment: Use 64bit JDK... 32 bit has a limit ~800MB.

Comment: I want 10240Mb(10 GB), I haved chose the 64-bit version

Comment: 64-bit would not be in `Program Files x86`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have an 64bit JDK, add  the option -d64 in the VM options in order to force Java to run in 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 10GB heap size with a 32-bit JVM, [see here why](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241105).

Your screenshot confirms that you are running the app under 32-bit JVM because you have configured the JDK in `Program Files (x86)` directory, which is used for 32-bit app versions.

Either add a new 64-bit JDK from `Program Files` directory and configure your project to use this new JDK or change the `JRE` in the run/debug configuration to the location of the 64-bit Java on your system.

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded 64-bit jdk, and solved the problem.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work